# Can I pass the output from Date.toString() to the Date constructor?

Tags: javascript, date, tostring

I have the output from Date.toString() and need to convert it back to a Date:

```
var dateString = new Date().toString();
// in Chrome: "Tue Nov 14 2017 09:06:46 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Zeit)"
// in IE11:   "Tue Nov 14 2017 09:07:38 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Zeit)"
// in FF:     "Tue Nov 14 2017 09:08:15 GMT+0100"
```

#### Can I do this?

```
var date = new Date(dateString);
```

I need to support IE11, Chrome and FF. I have tried it in these browsers and it works (on my machine).

However I'm not sure if this is safe because several sources say that you should not parse Date strings (e.g. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Several_ways_to_create_a_Date_object)). Is this valid for for the output of Date.toString() too?

Should I use moment.js?

Unfortunately I'm not in control of the code which generates the date string.

Comment: Implementations are required to parse the format generated by their own *toString* and *toUTCString* methods, see [*ECMA-262 §20.3.3.2*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date.parse): "*the value produced by Date.parse is implementation-dependent when given any String value that does not conform to the Date Time String Format (20.3.1.16) and that could not be produced in that implementation by the toString or toUTCString method.*" Obviously if follows that browsers may not correctly parse strings produced by other implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try and you'll have your answer.

```
console.log(new Date(new Date().toString())); // 2017-11-14T08:38:09.000Z
```

Comment: *I have tried it in these browsers and it works (on my machine).* OP already mentioned that.